# How to make a ForeignKey field in models, display text name instead of a URL in admin view?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm using django 1.4, I have a ForeignKey field in my model and on the admin view it shows the FK field as a URL link to the object in view mode, how can I change it to just show text instead of a url link?
Can this be done through widgets in the forms.ModelForm?

Thanks!

FK model:

```
class Regions(models.Model):
    cloud_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False)
    region_value = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    region_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.region_name

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('cloud_type', 'region_value')
        verbose_name = _("Region")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Regions")
```

The URL link shows up in admin view after I make a selection in the dropdown box and hit Save as a hyperlink. It creates html like this:

```
<div class="field-box">                                                                
<label class="inline">Region:</label>                        
<p><a href="/admin/app/regions/3/">US East</a></p>
</div>
```

admin.py

```
class GlobalSettings(admin.StackedInline):
    model = mymodels.GlobalSettings
    form = GlobalSettingsForm

fieldsets = ((None,{'fields':(('dell_region')}),)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

change the method `__str__` or `__unicode__` of the fk model to return the data that you wants, for example:

```py
class FKModel(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.some_field
```

the name of the method depends if you are using python 2 o 3, use `def __str__(self):` for python 3 and `def __unicode__(self):` for python 2

Comment: Unfortunately that's not it. I already have
    `def __unicode__(self):`  
        `return self.region_name`
defined in the FK model where region_name is a CharField()

Comment: please show the FK model and where is the url that is showing up.

Comment: Thanks @Diego Puente,
I posted the FK above with details.

Comment: ok, try to post a screenshot of the urls links and  show the admin.py code, maybe i'll make a better idea.

Comment: Updated the post.

Comment: i think that the problem should be in `GlobalSettingsForm` or maybe in a custom admin template if this exists. Please add the code of `GlobalSettingsForm`